# Is there a Dart utility for converting a flat list into a nested one?

Tags: list, multidimensional-array, dart, nested

It's a common problem here, but I couldn't find any simplified methods for Dart in particular - how can I convert a list like this

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

into a list like this

`[[1, 2], [3,4], [5,6]]`

assuming there are no extra elements after this?

Comment: I think,  no such built-in method or utility.

Comment: How about the Dart quiver library: https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.iterables/partition.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dart Quiver package is a set of utility libraries for Dart that makes using many Dart libraries easier and more convenient or adds additional functionality (https://github.com/google/quiver-dart).

You can use the **partition** function from **quiver** iterables library as follows.

```
import 'package:quiver/iterables.dart';

main() {
  var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  # Use partition function to segment lists into chunks of size 2
  var newList = partition<int>(list, 2);

  print (newList);

}
```

Result

```
[[1, 2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
List<int> temp = [];
List<List<int>> newList = list.fold<List<List<int>>>([], (newList, i) {
  if (temp.length < 2) {
     temp.add(i);
  } 
  if (temp.length >= 2) {
     List<int> newValue = new List<int>.from(temp);
     newList.add(newValue);
     temp.clear();
  }
  return newList;
});
print(newList);
```